# Error in selecting rows with "!" operator in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I try to select rows using the `!` operator

```
d = data.table(a = 1:3, b = c(TRUE, FALSE,FALSE))

d [b==FALSE]
#    a     b
# 1: 2 FALSE
# 2: 3 FALSE


d [!b]
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found
```

Shouldn't it be evaluated if it is an expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `data.table`, when `i` is a symbol, it is evaluated in the calling scope (see ?data.table `i` argument explanation) and not within the frame of the data.table. This is because we allow subsetting (or joining) data.tables using another data.table, i.e., `i` can be another data.table.

```
require(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(x=1:3, y=4:6)
dt2 = data.table(x=2:3, z=7:8)

dt1[dt2, on="x"] # dt2 needs to be looked up first in the calling scope
```

Because of this feature, *symbol* in `i` needs to be wrapped with `()` so that it's seen as an expression (as opposed to a symbol), which is sufficient to understand that it needs to be evaluated within the frame of a data.table. That is:

```
dt1[, id := c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]
dt1[(id)] # rows 1 and 3
```

When you use `!<symbol>`, the "!" is caught and removed, and the rest of the expression is first evaluated and then "!" is introduced back.. (but done efficiently without materialising intermediate data), i.e.,

```
dt1[!dt2, on="x"]
```

computes the matching row indices by first computing the matching row indices for `dt1[dt2, on="x"]` and then obtaining the indices corresponding to "!" by taking the difference.

Therefore, we'll need a `()` when used with "!" as well so that it's seen as an expression as opposed to a symbol.

```
dt1[!(id)] # works
dt1[(!id)] # also works
```

In general, this usage of subsetting a logical vector which is a column in the data.table is extremely rare compared to the usage and advantages of subsetting using another data.table.

---

This'll become a lot better when better scoping rules are implemented for `i` argument. See [#633](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/633).

Answer (score 1):

We need to put it inside brackets

```
d [!(b)]
#   a     b
#1: 2 FALSE
#2: 3 FALSE
```

Comment: While this provides the answer that gives the result OP is looking for, I find it tangential to OP's actual question "shouldn't this work?" due to lack of an explanation as to "why"..

Comment: @Arun Yes, that makes sense and your post gives that explanation well.